# Nested form: creating an object related to two object that are also related

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

UPDATE: I did something that works, which I will write up as my own answer to this question. But it bypasses the guide_params function, so I think it is not secure. I'd appreciate if someone had a better way to do this.

I have three objects. The parent is Guide, and I have a nested form to create it. Guide belongs_to CityObj and CountryObj. These two models has_many Guides.

I'm able to use accepts_nested_attributes_for to properly initialize the Guide-CityObj and Guide-CountryObj relationships.

The wrinkle is that CityObj and CountryObj are related to each other. CityObj belongs_to CountryObj, and CountryObj has_many CityObj. I don't know how to initialize the CityObj-CountryObj relationship when creating a guide.

Also, CountryObj.name is unique (There is only one France), and CityObj.name/CountryObj.id are unique (There is only one Paris, France, but there is also a Paris, USA). But I don't want to use validation to prevent Guides from being created in existing cities/countries. Paris, France should be able to have many guides. So I have to be able to handle duplicates in the controller.

Guide.rb

```
class Guide < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city_obj
  belongs_to :country_obj

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :city_obj, :country_obj
end
```

country_obj.rb

```
class CountryObj < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guides, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :city_obj, dependent: :destroy
end
```

city_obj.rb

```
class CityObj < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guide, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :country_obj

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :country_obj   # This is not working
end
```

I think I have to update guide_params in the guide controller to pass CountryObj to CityObj. I tried this:

```
def guide_params
      params.require(:guide).permit(:name, 
                                    :description, 
                                    country_obj_attributes: [:name],
                                    city_obj_attributes: [:name, country_obj_attributes: [:name]],
                                    guide_pics_attributes: [:picture]) 
end
```

My create function calls

```
@guide = current_user.build_guide(guide_params)
```

That gives

```
@guide.city_obj = <a city object>
@guide.country_obj = <a country object>
@guide.country_obj.city_obj = nil
```

How can I set that final relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is safe, because it bypasses my guide_params method that limits params that are required.

To make this work, I manually set the coutnry_obj and city_obj in the controller.

```
def create
  @guide = current_user.build_guide(guide_params)

  set_city_country

  if @guide.save
     ...

end
```

I use the set_city_country function both for create and update:

```
def set_city_country
  # Building guide with guide_params is not setting city_obj.country_obj.
  # Also need to manaually ensure city_obj/country_obj and country_obj are unique

  country = params[:guide][:country_obj_attributes][:name]
  city = params[:guide][:city_obj_attributes][:name]

  @guide.country_obj = CountryObj.find_or_create_by(name: country)
  @guide.city_obj = CityObj.find_or_create_by(name: city, 
                                        country_obj_id: @guide.country_obj.id)
  @guide.city_obj.country_obj = @guide.country_obj
end
```